How do I properly insert binary data to SQL Server from a PHP file upload?
I have a page that allows the user to upload an Excel spreadsheet and I want to save the contents of it to a table in my SQL Server database.  However, when I try I get the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. in /var/www/test/upload.php:94 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/test/upload.php(94): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/test/upload.php on line 94

Here is my PHP code:
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $manufacturer = $_POST['manufacturer'];

    if (isset($_FILES['spreadsheet_file']) && $_FILES['spreadsheet_file']['error'] == 0) {
        $filePath = $_FILES['spreadsheet_file']['tmp_name'];
        $fileContent = fopen($filePath, 'rb');
    } else {
        die("No file uploaded or an error occurred: {$_FILES['spreadsheet_file']['error']}");
    }

    try {
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("
          UPDATE  Test
          SET     manufacturer = :manufacturer,
                  spreadsheet_file = :fileContent
          WHERE   id = :id");
      $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
      $stmt->bindParam(':manufacturer', $manufacturer);
      $stmt->bindParam(':fileContent', $fileContent, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Error inserting the file into the database: " . $e->getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (is_resource($fileContent)) {
            fclose($fileContent);
        }
    }

    $stmt->execute();
}
?>

I have confirmed that the spreadsheet_file column is a VARBINARY.  I even ran this alter just to be sure:
ALTER TABLE ContractConfig ALTER COLUMN spreadsheet_file VARBINARY(MAX);

What do I need to do in order to get that file into the database?  I should note that the PHP is running on a separate server from the database so I can't use bulk loading.

It looks like this $stmt->bindParam(':fileContent', $fileContent, PDO::PARAM_LOB); is creating an nvarchar(max) instead of a varbinary(max). Is $fileContent a byte array (or similar)?

fopen returns a file pointer, not the file content. file_get_contents is a quick way to get the entire contents of a file. Do you really want to save the file content itself into the database though? Why not just store the file on disk somewhere, and store the path to it in your database, so you can retrieve it easily?

@ADyson I definitely would prefer to store it on the filesystem but this is a stop-gap measure until I can do that.

@TN woops, thought this was mysql.

The problem lies in how the file content is being bound to the SQL query. PHP's PDO is treating the file handle as a string, causing a data type mismatch with the VARBINARY column in the database.
 <?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $manufacturer = $_POST['manufacturer'];

        if (isset($_FILES['spreadsheet_file']) && $_FILES['spreadsheet_file']['error'] == 0) {
            $filePath = $_FILES['spreadsheet_file']['tmp_name'];
            <?php
            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                $id = $_POST['id'];
                $manufacturer = $_POST['manufacturer'];

                if (isset($_FILES['spreadsheet_file']) && $_FILES['spreadsheet_file']['error'] == 0) {
                    $filePath = $_FILES['spreadsheet_file']['tmp_name'];
                    $fileContent = file_get_contents($filePath); 
        } else {
            die("No file uploaded or an error occurred: {$_FILES['spreadsheet_file']['error']}");
    }

    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("
            UPDATE Test
            SET manufacturer = :manufacturer,
                spreadsheet_file = :fileContent
            WHERE id = :id");
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':manufacturer', $manufacturer);
        $stmt->bindParam(':fileContent', $fileContent, PDO::PARAM_LOB); // Bind file content
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Error inserting the file into the database: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>

